# CSS child selector in styled component doesn't append changes

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

I have one component that is an input wrapped in a styled `div` component and a second component that uses the first one but it should change some of the CSS style using child selectors. The first component I have is

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 2px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
`;

function EditInput() {
  return (
    <Container className="testClass">
      <input />
    </Container>
  );
}

export { EditInput };
```

while the second one is

```
import React from "react";
import { EditInput } from "./EditInput";
import styled from "styled-components";

const EditInputs = styled(EditInput)`
  div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
  }
  .testClass {
    background: red;
  }
  &:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
  }
  & > *:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
  }
`;

export function Input() {
  return <EditInputs />;
}
```

This returns me an input field but the child selectors' CSS does not apply changes. I tried with multiple approaches, as you can see, but none of them works. However, if I add `background: red` into `Container` from the first component, the color gets changed.

I prepared a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bassi-41zxn8?file=/src/Input.js:0-382) here so you can check it out yourself. Do you know how can I fix this and why does this occur? Thanks in advance o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styled factory depends on the classname prop being passed down.

```
function EditInput({ className }) {
  return (
    <Container className={className}>
      <input />
    </Container>
  );
}
```